# export meta-analysis output

Tags: r, write.table

This is an output that I get from meta-analysis. How can I export the output to a .txt or .csv or any other file type were I can refer to it later istead of doing the analysis again?

```
result #this gives the following output

Random-Effects Model (k = 11; tau^2 estimator: REML)

tau^2 (estimated amount of total heterogeneity): 0.1027 (SE = 0.0532)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):      0.3205
I^2 (total heterogeneity / total variability):   95.22%
H^2 (total variability / sampling variability):  20.92

Test for Heterogeneity: 
Q(df = 10) = 212.2659, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

estimate       se     zval     pval    ci.lb    ci.ub          
  6.4863   0.1048  61.9000   <.0001   6.2809   6.6916      *** 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: How exactly do you want output file formatted? If you want to save the R object directly so you can reload it later, look into the `save()` function (but this does not produce text files). If you want to turn the results into some tabular format, maybe look at the `broom` package. If would help if you more specific about what the desired result is.

Comment: @MrFlick There isn't a specific format. I just want to save the output into a folder as is.

Comment: Look at `capture.output()` or maybe `sink()` if you want to capture exactly what you see there.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you. `capture.output()` worked. The `tidy()` in`broom` package is interesting; however, it seems it can be applied for linear regression and hypotheiss testing outputs. It didn't equally apply to my output in the question.

Comment: alternatively write all df loading and code in a script file for reproducibility or - the worst, but effective version - you can copy paste your output into excel and separate it by "space"...does quite a clean job...but it's dirty.

Answer (score 2):

```
sink(file = "OUTPUT.txt")
RE_model <- your_model
RE_model
sink(NULL)
```